# How do I resolve the PHP Notice: DS Constant already defined?

Tags: php, magento, cron

When I run a certain script from a cron job, for some reason it runs into an error, which kills off the script:

```
PHP Notice: Constant DS already defined in /home/mysite/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 27
```

I know the script itself runs the following command:

```
require_once $root . 'app/Mage.php';
```

What's weird is that it works fine every time I run the script manually (no error or PHP notice).

Would appreciate any ideas on how to resolve this.

Thank you.

Comment: A notice doesn't kill a cron job. And you're including something twice. Or just happen to have error_reporting only enabled for the CLI interpreter, not the webserver setup.

Comment: this shows that a constant name `DS` is defined already and again somewhere you are trying to reassign it. which is not possible. because constant value cannot change while program execution.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the problem with DS constant you should define it like the following

```
if (!defined('DS')) {
    define('DS', 'MY_DS_VALUE');
}
```

but it is not a solution of entire problem, ultimately you should prevent duplicate code inclusion. 
Could you post the full code of the script?